# Changing <textarea> text once a picture is clicked with javascript

Tags: javascript, textarea

I want to have the text inside of a textarea change once a picture is clicked. How would I go about doing this inside of javascript.

HTML

```
  <div id="textArea">
                <div id="instruction">
                <p> *Type a word here, and click diffrent styles and sizes</p>
                </div> 
                    <textarea name="word">  </textarea>
                </div>
```

java script, which I am still new at so pardon if this is totally incorrect

```
window.onload = init;


function init(){
document.getElementById("buttonImage").onclick = changeFont;


function changeFont(){
    document.getElementById("textArea").style.fontFamily = "'Oswald', sans-serif";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the textarea element, so:

```
document.getElementsByName("word")[0].style.fontFamily = "'Oswald', sans-serif";
```

but there are much better ways of going about this. Consider using CSS or a class.

Comment: thanks for the response, by saying try using CSS or class. Do you mind giving me a explanation about that?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use jquery:**

```
$("#word").addClass('classname');
```

It's best practice to keep CSS out of your logic.

jQuery makes traversing the Document Object Model easier.

[jquery.com](http://jquery.com)